# How to trigger an event when a TinyMCE modal dialog opens

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need an event when a TinyMCE modal dialog is opened. I found no such thing in their editor. Is there any way to overwrite the existing TinyMCE in-built function (e.g."fireOpenEvent" function in tinymce.js file).[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a "post render" hook in TinyMCE 5, no. It looks like you've built a custom dialog; when the `editor.windowManager.open()` call returns, the dialog should be fully rendered.